# How to stop water from overlaying with boat object

Tags: animation, ocean-simulation

[image]I have been creating animations through blender using the ocean generator and a Lego boat - see attached image - I have been using shrink wrap and copy location to make the boat float but when I play the animation, the water actually goes inside the object as if it was not there - how do I stop the water from entering the object?

Comment: One way is using a Boolean modifier - you add a „boat negative“ object to the z axis which is parented to the boat and Boolean cuts the ocean away

Comment: @Chris agreed, but the invisible boat negative should also be solid, without the inside space.

Comment: Thanks @Chris !